# Can I set remote-allow-origins without using a wildcard in Selenium?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I am having a WebSocket issue with Selenium WebDriver, the same issue described [here](https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/xL5-13_qGaA). The solution to the problem was to add the `--remote-allow-origins=*` argument to my driver's ChromeOptions. However, I do not want to use a wildcard for this parameter. I want to set it to something that will only allow a connection from my application.

I believe the solution will involve predetermining the WebDriver's port. This is my best attempt, but it is not working:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--incognito", "--app=" + linkedform);

int port;
try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
    port = serverSocket.getLocalPort();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:" + port);
ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(port).build();
this.chrome = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

Am I going down the right track? Is this even possible?

Comment: How about hardcoding the port and  configuring the remote origins to be `options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins="+ service.getUrl())`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule it's certainly an option, but I was hoping to use a dynamically assigned port.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket issue is now fixed from selenium 4.8.2/4.8.3, there's no need to add "--remote-allow-origins=*" to the chrome options during invocation. Instead we can now directly update the selenium dependencies in our pom.xml.

## Update Logs:
v4.8.3

- Supported CDP versions: 85, 109, 110, 111
- Fix bug preventing adding items to ArrayList for Selenium Manager command

## v4.8.2

- Supported CDP versions: 85, 109, 110, 111
- [grid] Enabling `detectDrivers` original behaviour.
- Fix NPE regression in 4.8.0 (#11701)
- Implement DriverFinder completely independent of Service classes (#11491)
- [grid] Allow LocalNode to be extended for customisation (#11718)
- InvalidSelectorException extends WebDriverException (#11727)
- Deprecate CDP instance methods in FirefoxDriver
- Adding allowHosts to GeckoDriverService
- [grid] Passing language env var to child containers
- [grid] Removing unknown capability extensions for IE
- [bidi] Ensure removing listeners does not cause an error
- Process Selenium Manager output as JSON (#11663)
- [grid] Support remote downloads in Grid (#11702)
- Adding `remote-allow-origins` for Chrome
- Invoking Selenium Manager only with `--browser
- [grid] Adding `remote-allow-origins` for Chrome stereotypes
- Overloaded constructors to configure connect and read timeouts for WebDriver objects (#11532)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");

options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8080/leiloes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , Updating the Selenium Dependencies to 4.8.x and above solved the issue.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.8.3

Answer (score -1):

### Source Code:-

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class SeleniumJavaDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    // Open Google
    driver.get("https://google.com");

    // Close browser
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

Please check the version of google-chrome and chromedriver must:

### Install Chrome in Linux:-

1. sudo curl -sS -o – https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
2. sudo bash -c "echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list"
3. sudo apt-get update

For remove

4. sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable

For Install

5. sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
6. google-chrome --version

### Download chrome Driver:-

7. wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver_linux64.zip
8. unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
9. sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
10. sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
11. sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

### Compile in linux:-

1. javac -cp selenium-server.jar:. SeleniumJavaDemo.java

### Run in Linux:-

2. java -cp selenium-server.jar:. SeleniumJavaDemo

:) Successfully executed ...

Comment: No need to add chromedriver 
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");

Comment: MUST ADD:
`ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); ` 
`options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");`
`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).