# Selenium project stops working after updating to 4.8.3

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My selenium Java project was working fine on Selenium version 4.7.0 till I updated Google Chrome to version 111.

According to this thread, updating Selenium to version 4.8.3 should fix the incompatibilities:
[Can I set remote-allow-origins without using a wildcard in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674124/can-i-set-remote-allow-origins-without-using-a-wildcard-in-selenium)

So I updated the selenium project and got chromedriver version 111 to work with Google Chrome 111.
But now the Java program won't start either due to the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'host.name', ip: '123.123.123.123'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at AutoChrome.Main.init(Main.java:41)
    at AutoChrome.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.0', java.version: '11.0.18'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:208)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 8 more
```

Code line 41, which throws the error:

> driver = new ChromeDriver();

The chromedriver file is executable. Version 112 of chromedriver won't work either.

What could be the reason and solution?

Comment: For us the update to v4.8.3 is even breaking a working setup of v4.8.0. We are using a standalone selenium node on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");" to your ChromeDriver and it should work fine. If not, then check if your Firewall prevents the chromedriver.exe file to run.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```