# chrome webdriver sampler fails when run from redhat 8

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, redhat, jmeter-plugins

Scenario:

Running tests from jemter in a redhat server
Results: getting zero result

[image]

System is RHEL 8, running in headless mode. This runs without issue on Windows. I have triple checked the chromedriver version and my browser version and they match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging), when your test fails it normally contains the failure reason, your screenshot only indicates the fact that your test failed and no Samplers were run at all

Things to consider:

- if you're running the ChromeDriver under superuser you need to pass [`--no-sandbox` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695438/why-do-i-need-no-sandbox-to-run-selenium-chromedriver-even-with-admin-privil) to it.
- you might also need to add [`--remote-allow-origins=*` argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674124/can-i-set-remote-allow-origins-without-using-a-wildcard-in-selenium) as well if not yet

Comment: after adding --no-sandbox able to run all test cases. thanks